# DPDK hashtable value allocation in huge pages

Tags: c, linux, hash, hashtable, dpdk

There is a hashtable API in DPDK inside `lib/hash/rte_hash.h`. And it has the following function for adding key-value:

```
int rte_hash_add_key_data(const struct rte_hash *h, const void *key, void *data);
```

The desciption includes *"It is the responsibility of the application to manage any memory associated with the old value."* from what we can conclude, that we can't pass as value(`data`) the address of variable, which is on stack, because DPDK will not copy it into internal storage (in appropriate memory). So the memory behind the `data`(value) pointer should allocated by application itself.

The easiest example:

```
struct mykey key;
struct myvalue *value = malloc(sizeof(struct myvalue));
if (!value)
    return;
value->a = 123;
value->b = 'b';
ret = rte_hash_add_key_data(hash_table, &key, &value)
// ...
```

But seems that this way is not the best and has performance penalties (`malloc` obviously will not give us huge page memory).
DPDK is famous for data structures and algorithms, which are adapted for performance. But here in this API the need for correct allocation is not highlighted in any way. It turns out that the one has to somehow allocate memory for each value in hugepage by himself? If so, how can this be done in C?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a version of `malloc()` that uses hugepages for its backing memory?

Comment: @Shawn Yep, but also I'm asking if such using this API is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your data which the value pointed should be some data structures used in DPDK packet fast path, like session, route table. Typically, these data structures allocated from DPDK mempool which using hugepage memory.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of using route/session table (with mempool backing memory) with this hashtable API (lib/hash/rte_hash.h)?

Comment: @NK-cell You can refer to l3fwd_lpm.c : setup_lpm-->rte_lpm6_add

Comment: "should be some data structures used in DPDK packet fast path" - OK, what if I need my own data structure? Not session table or route table

Answer (score 0):

You can use DPDK's [`librte_malloc` API](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__malloc_8h.html) for a `malloc` like interface (which is NUMA aware and has API for allocating for a specific NUMA socket if you need that), or the [`librte_mempool` API](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__mempool_8h.html) to create a memory pool and allocate fixed sized objects from there (I'll note that both API documents link to usable examples).

In either case, it should probably be noted that the hash table implementation doesn't actually care what your `data` pointer is (and you'll see that some examples just stuff an integer value cast as a pointer into it).

Comment: *"an integer value cast as a pointer into it"* - this is obviously UB if variable is on stack (I think that's what you meant) and its scope ended.